# python command-line-style application with tkinter

Tags: python, command-line, tkinter

In the application I'm currently working on, i want to include a feature in which the administrator has access to a sort of command line.
This is not the actual command line, instead it looks for keywords inside a Textbox that I define, and runs their linked functions with the input parameters.
For instance:

```
get user data: erikthered
```

...would run the method `self.user_data('erikthered')`, but I'm unsure how to get to this step elegantly, without using messy things like `eval` or `exec`.
These features should ideally also work for multiple parameters.
I apologise if this question is considered subjective, but I haven't really programmed something like this before, and I value other people's insights.
Thanks

**UPDATE**
One way to do this, using `exec`, is to use a dictionary, like so:

```
    links = {'get users':'self.get_users(parameters)', 'get user data':'self.get_user_data(parameters)'}

    terminal = self.terminal
    line = str(terminal.index(INSERT).split('.')[0])
    #get index of line

    line = terminal.get(line+'.0', line+'.end')
    splitline = line.split(':')

    command = splitline[0]
    parameters = splitline[1].split(',')
    exec(links[command])
```

This is the code I have to get the text that the user has typed, bound to a return press. But I would prefer not to use `exec`.

Comment: Can i see the full code?

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with Tkinter or the actual command-line, or is this purely about how to parse and evaluate some made up command language?

Comment: You're right, it probably has more to do with parsing the inputs, than tkinter or the actual command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `exec`, you can do a dictionary of functions:

```
def get_user_data(*args):
    print(*args)
# dictionary of functions
functions = {'get user data': get_user_data}

line = "get user data: erikthered, turtle"

# parse line
command, params = line.split(":")
params = [p.strip() for p in params.split(",")]
functions[command](*params)
```

Comment: out of interest, would `params.replace(" ", "").split(",")`, instead of the list comp, also work?

Comment: In this case, there will be problems with arguments containing spaces, e.g. "green turtle" will become "greenturtle".